# Scraping a website that may require login - jsoup

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to scrape a website that possibly requires authentication. When I try the following code I get an error :

> org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must
>   be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml.
>   Mimetype=application/json; charset=utf-8,
>   URL=https://sso.mims.com/Account/Signin   at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:547)
>     at
>   org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
>     at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
>     at com.aiingov.proc.MedScraper.main(MedScraper.java:49)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String url = "https://sso.mims.com/Account/Signin";
            String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36";

            Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .execute();

            response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .data("action", "login")
                    .data("login", "xxxxx")
                    .data("password", "xxxxx")
                    .data("auto_login", "1")
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .followRedirects(true)
                    .execute();           

            Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.mims.com/india/drug/info/abacavir/abacavir?type=full&mtype=generic")
                    .cookies(response.cookies())
                    .userAgent(userAgent)
                    .get();

            System.out.println(document);

            Elements elements = document.body().select("*");

               for (Element element : elements) {
                   System.out.println(element.ownText());
               }
```

Without the login code in place I get the following output:

> You will be redirected to your destination shortly.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `ignoreContentType` method.

```
 Jsoup.connect(url).ignoreContentType(true);//chain any other methods
```

Description of the method from the JSoup Docs:

> Ignore the document's Content-Type when parsing the response. By default this is false, an unrecognised content-type will cause an IOException to be thrown. (This is to prevent producing garbage by attempting to parse a JPEG binary image, for example.) Set to true to force a parse attempt regardless of content type.

Comment: Thanks.Tried this but I continue to get the same error.

Comment: @serendipity can you point out the line in your code example that is throwing the error? Did you try adding it to both of your `JSoup.connect` methods?

Comment: After adding this to both of the jsoup.connect methods I don't get an error anymore. What I do get is the HTML of the page that says "You will be redirected to your destination shortly." How do I get to the page I want to and get the data from there?

Comment: @serendipity If you just navigate to that page normally in a browser, does it take a while for the content to load?

Comment: It is pretty instantaneous. I'm not sure why this redirect page comes in first while scraping. When I manually go to the website I don't see this page. Could it be some sort of a firewall setup by the website to disallow scraping?